# Convert Webview to PDF in android

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, webview, android-webview

I am using this library to convert webview to PDF.
https://github.com/pramodkr123/ConvertWebViewToPdfDemo
and using this function. Write permissions are already granted. Still code falls in failure category with no exception and failure message. Any luck how to solve this.

```
   private fun webviewToPDFLibrary(){
    val directory =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/PDFTest/")
    val fileName = "Test.pdf"

    val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(requireActivity())
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait")
    progressDialog.show()
    PdfView.createWebPrintJob(
        requireActivity(),
        mBinding.webviewDashboard,
        directory,
        fileName,
        object : PdfView.Callback {
            override fun success(path: String) {
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                PdfView.openPdfFile(
                    requireActivity(), getString(R.string.app_name),
                    "Do you want to open the pdf file?$fileName", path
                )
                requireContext().T("Success")
            }

            override fun failure() {
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                requireContext().T("failure")
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?.

Comment: No error. The code falls in the failure method.

Comment: Print the failure log and check it out.

Comment: Have you given all media access permission to the application may be that also make the problem.

Comment: CAMERA, READ, WRITE, RECORD AUDIO, INTERNET, and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
All these permissions are given.

Comment: You cannot put .pdf files in DCIM directory on Android 11+ devices. DCIM is for picture files.

Comment: @blackapps. Yes, I have changed the directory to downloads.

Comment: Vey fine that it works now.

Comment: No, It is working till android 10. From android 11 the library has some issues and it crashes the code.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 10 (API 29) and higher, the  `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not recommended. Also, it is not supported by Android 13 (API 33).

I recommend you use this [WebViewToPdf](https://github.com/amir-asdp/WebViewToPdf) library instead, which can handle all the required permissions automatically according to the Android OS Version and it is supported by Android 13.

The following code shows how it works:

```
File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/MyExapmleApp/");
String fileName = "Exapmle.pdf";


//Receive webView in "onFinished(WebView webView, String url)" callback and pass it to the following method.

WebViewToPdf.convertWebViewToPdf(mContext, webView, directory, fileName, new WebViewToPdf.OnConvertResultListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String pdfFilePath) {
                WebViewToPdf.openPdfFile(mContext, pdfFilePath, new WebViewToPdf.OnOpenResultListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied() {
                        WebViewToPdf.buildPdfPermissionsRationalDialog(mContext, WebViewToPdf.PERMISSION_DIALOG_ENGLISH).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String failMessage) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, failMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled() {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Convert Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied() {
                WebViewToPdf.buildPdfPermissionsRationalDialog(mContext, WebViewToPdf.PERMISSION_DIALOG_ENGLISH).show();
            }
            
        });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).